# Unable to install web3 on windows 10

Tags: web3js, nodejs, installation, npm

This is the error I get when I try to install web3 on my machine.

After installing git I have another issue:

```
C:\Windows\system32> npm install web3
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'web3'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.11.3
3 info using node@v12.11.0
4 verbose npm-session aab7a7e3a168fc24
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/web3 30ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for web3@latest fetched in 101ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 148ms
.................
834 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xhr2-cookies 13ms (from cache)
835 silly pacote version manifest for xhr2-cookies@1.1.0 fetched in 19ms
836 silly resolveWithNewModule xhr2-cookies@1.1.0 checking installable status
837 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookiejar 59ms (from cache)
838 silly pacote range manifest for cookiejar@^2.1.1 fetched in 64ms
839 silly resolveWithNewModule cookiejar@2.1.2 checking installable status
840 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/oboe 12ms (from cache)
841 silly pacote version manifest for oboe@2.1.4 fetched in 18ms
842 silly resolveWithNewModule oboe@2.1.4 checking installable status
843 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-https 15ms (from cache)
844 silly pacote range manifest for http-https@^1.0.0 fetched in 21ms
845 silly resolveWithNewModule http-https@1.0.0 checking installable status
846 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for websocket@github:web3-js/WebSocket-Node#polyfill/globalThis Error while executing:
846 silly fetchPackageMetaData undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git
846 silly fetchPackageMetaData
846 silly fetchPackageMetaData
846 silly fetchPackageMetaData spawn git ENOENT
847 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
848 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 8054ms
849 silly saveTree system32
849 silly saveTree +-- git@0.1.5
849 silly saveTree | `-- mime@1.2.9
849 silly saveTree +-- mime@1.2.9
849 silly saveTree `-- web3@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   +-- web3-bzz@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | +-- got@9.6.0
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- @sindresorhus/is@0.14.0
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- @szmarczak/http-timer@1.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- defer-to-connect@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- cacheable-request@6.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- clone-response@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- mimic-response@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- get-stream@5.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- pump@3.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- end-of-stream@1.4.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | `-- once@1.4.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   |   `-- wrappy@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- once@1.4.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- http-cache-semantics@4.0.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- keyv@3.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- json-buffer@3.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- lowercase-keys@2.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- normalize-url@4.5.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- responselike@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- lowercase-keys@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- decompress-response@3.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- duplexer3@0.1.4
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- get-stream@4.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- lowercase-keys@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- mimic-response@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- p-cancelable@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- to-readable-stream@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | `-- url-parse-lax@3.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | |   `-- prepend-http@2.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | +-- swarm-js@0.1.39
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- bluebird@3.5.5
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- buffer@5.4.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- base64-js@1.3.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- ieee754@1.1.13
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- decompress@4.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- decompress-tar@4.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- file-type@5.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- is-stream@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- tar-stream@1.6.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- bl@1.2.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | +-- readable-stream@2.3.6
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | +-- inherits@2.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | +-- isarray@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | +-- process-nextick-args@2.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | +-- string_decoder@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | | `-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | `-- safe-buffer@5.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- buffer-alloc@1.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | +-- buffer-alloc-unsafe@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | `-- buffer-fill@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- fs-constants@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- readable-stream@2.3.6
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- to-buffer@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- xtend@4.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- decompress-tarbz2@4.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- file-type@6.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- seek-bzip@1.0.5
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- commander@2.8.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | |   `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- unbzip2-stream@1.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- through@2.3.8
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- decompress-targz@4.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- decompress-unzip@4.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- file-type@3.9.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- get-stream@2.3.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- object-assign@4.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- pify@2.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- yauzl@2.10.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- buffer-crc32@0.2.13
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- fd-slicer@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |     `-- pend@1.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- graceful-fs@4.2.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- make-dir@1.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- pify@3.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- pify@2.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- strip-dirs@2.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- is-natural-number@4.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- eth-lib@0.1.27
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- bn.js@4.11.8
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- elliptic@6.5.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- brorand@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- hash.js@1.1.7
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- minimalistic-assert@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- hmac-drbg@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- minimalistic-assert@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- keccakjs@0.2.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- browserify-sha3@0.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- js-sha3@0.6.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- sha3@1.2.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- nan@2.13.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- nano-json-stream-parser@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- servify@0.1.12
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- body-parser@1.19.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- bytes@3.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- content-type@1.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- debug@2.6.9
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- ms@2.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- depd@1.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- http-errors@1.7.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- inherits@2.0.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- setprototypeof@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- statuses@1.5.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- toidentifier@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- iconv-lite@0.4.24
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- safer-buffer@2.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- on-finished@2.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- ee-first@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- qs@6.7.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- raw-body@2.4.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- unpipe@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- type-is@1.6.18
849 silly saveTree   | | | | |   +-- media-typer@0.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | |   `-- mime-types@2.1.24
849 silly saveTree   | | | | |     `-- mime-db@1.40.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- cors@2.8.5
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- vary@1.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- express@4.17.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- accepts@1.3.7
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- negotiator@0.6.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- array-flatten@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- content-disposition@0.5.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- cookie-signature@1.0.6
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- cookie@0.4.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- encodeurl@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- escape-html@1.0.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- etag@1.8.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- finalhandler@1.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- parseurl@1.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- fresh@0.5.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- merge-descriptors@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- methods@1.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- parseurl@1.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- proxy-addr@2.0.5
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- forwarded@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- ipaddr.js@1.9.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- range-parser@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- send@0.17.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- destroy@1.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- mime@1.6.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- ms@2.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- serve-static@1.14.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- utils-merge@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- request@2.88.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- aws-sign2@0.7.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- aws4@1.8.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- caseless@0.12.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- combined-stream@1.0.8
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- extend@3.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- forever-agent@0.6.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- form-data@2.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- asynckit@0.4.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- har-validator@5.1.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- ajv@6.10.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | +-- fast-deep-equal@2.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | +-- json-schema-traverse@0.4.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | `-- uri-js@4.2.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | |   `-- punycode@2.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- har-schema@2.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- http-signature@1.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- assert-plus@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- jsprim@1.4.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | +-- extsprintf@1.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | +-- json-schema@0.2.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | | `-- verror@1.10.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- sshpk@1.16.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   +-- asn1@0.2.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   +-- bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   | `-- tweetnacl@0.14.5
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   +-- dashdash@1.14.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   +-- ecc-jsbn@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   | `-- jsbn@0.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   +-- getpass@0.1.7
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   +-- jsbn@0.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | |   `-- tweetnacl@0.14.5
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- isstream@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- oauth-sign@0.9.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- performance-now@2.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- qs@6.5.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- tough-cookie@2.4.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | +-- psl@1.4.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | | `-- punycode@1.4.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | +-- tunnel-agent@0.6.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- uuid@3.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- xhr@2.5.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- global@4.3.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | +-- min-document@2.19.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | | `-- dom-walk@0.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   | `-- process@0.5.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   +-- is-function@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- parse-headers@2.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |     +-- for-each@0.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | |     | `-- is-callable@1.1.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | |     `-- string.prototype.trim@1.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       +-- define-properties@1.1.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | `-- object-keys@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       +-- es-abstract@1.14.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- es-to-primitive@1.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | | +-- is-date-object@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | | `-- is-symbol@1.0.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | |   `-- has-symbols@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- function-bind@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- has-symbols@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- has@1.0.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- is-regex@1.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- object-inspect@1.6.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | +-- string.prototype.trimleft@2.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       | `-- string.prototype.trimright@2.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |       `-- function-bind@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- ws@3.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- async-limiter@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- ultron@1.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- xhr-request-promise@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- xhr-request@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |     +-- buffer-to-arraybuffer@0.0.5
849 silly saveTree   | | |     +-- query-string@5.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | |     | +-- decode-uri-component@0.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |     | `-- strict-uri-encode@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |     +-- simple-get@2.8.1
849 silly saveTree   | | |     | `-- simple-concat@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |     +-- timed-out@4.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | |     `-- url-set-query@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- fs-extra@4.0.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- jsonfile@4.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- universalify@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- got@7.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- get-stream@3.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- is-plain-obj@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- is-retry-allowed@1.2.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- isurl@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | +-- has-to-string-tag-x@1.4.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | | `-- has-symbol-support-x@1.4.2
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- is-object@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- p-cancelable@0.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- p-timeout@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- p-finally@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- url-parse-lax@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- prepend-http@1.0.4
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- url-to-options@1.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- mime-types@2.1.24
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- mkdirp-promise@5.0.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- mkdirp@0.5.1
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- minimist@0.0.8
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- mock-fs@4.10.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- setimmediate@1.0.5
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- tar@4.4.13
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- chownr@1.1.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- fs-minipass@1.2.7
849 silly saveTree   | | | | `-- minipass@2.9.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | |   `-- yallist@3.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- minipass@2.9.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- minizlib@1.3.3
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- yallist@3.1.1
849 silly saveTree   | | `-- xhr-request-promise@0.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | `-- underscore@1.9.1
849 silly saveTree   +-- web3-core@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | +-- web3-core-helpers@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- web3-eth-iban@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- web3-utils@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | |   +-- eth-lib@0.2.7
849 silly saveTree   | | |   +-- ethjs-unit@0.1.6
849 silly saveTree   | | |   | +-- bn.js@4.11.6
849 silly saveTree   | | |   | `-- number-to-bn@1.7.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |   |   +-- bn.js@4.11.6
849 silly saveTree   | | |   |   `-- strip-hex-prefix@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |   |     `-- is-hex-prefixed@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |   +-- number-to-bn@1.7.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |   +-- randomhex@0.1.5
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- utf8@3.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | `-- web3-utils@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | +-- web3-core-method@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- web3-core-promievent@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | +-- any-promise@1.3.0
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- eventemitter3@3.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | `-- web3-core-subscriptions@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | +-- web3-core-requestmanager@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- web3-providers-http@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- xhr2-cookies@1.1.0
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- cookiejar@2.1.2
849 silly saveTree   | | +-- web3-providers-ipc@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | | | `-- oboe@2.1.4
849 silly saveTree   | | |   `-- http-https@1.0.0
849 silly saveTree   | | `-- web3-providers-ws@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | `-- web3-utils@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   +-- web3-eth-personal@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   | `-- web3-net@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   +-- web3-eth@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   +-- web3-net@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   +-- web3-shh@1.2.1
849 silly saveTree   `-- web3-utils@1.2.1
850 verbose stack Error: spawn git ENOENT
850 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
850 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
850 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
851 verbose cwd C:\Windows\system32
852 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
853 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "web3"
854 verbose node v12.11.0
855 verbose npm  v6.11.3
856 error code ENOENT
857 error syscall spawn git
858 error path git
859 error errno ENOENT
860 error enoent Error while executing:
860 error enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git
860 error enoent
860 error enoent
860 error enoent spawn git ENOENT
861 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
862 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Help would be appreciated!!! Thanks!

Comment: is `git` properly installed?

Comment: Now git is properly installed.

Comment: Did it resolve your problem?

Comment: No it did not, It added new problems. I added that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thanks Niklas Feurstein for guiding me through!!

I installed windows-build-tools using `npm install --global windows-build-tools`.

Installing git from an outside source (Not `npm install git`) worked for me.

After that `npm` started working magically fine to install everything I wanted.

Also before I was running the command prompt in regular mode but for this to work I needed it in administrator mode.